# Program crash after trying to draw chart

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I have an app, where user can select date (from/to), list of currencies, and then, display chart with some data. The chart, is just stacked bar chart, from `MPAndroidChart`. Recently, I've implemented `SwiperRefreshLayout`, so user can make more than just one api call. There's two cases of displaying chart:

**First (everything is working fine)**
When user will select for example 2 currencies, he could make another calls, but he can't exceed firstly picked amount of currencies. So in this case, he can pick one, or two currencies. No matter which ones.

**Second, program crashes**
User will pick X amount of currencies, the chart will be displayed, and after refreshing layout, user will pick X+1 currencies. This makes the program crash.

Since I've spend already a couple of days with this issue, I've tried to clear data, invalidating chart, etc. It turns out, that this command makes the program crash

```
mBinding.myChart.setCustom(myEntries)
```

I can run entire program without it, but it is needed, since it provides labels for chart.

Here's some code:

**Global variables**

```
    private var myChartData: MutableList<BarEntry> = mutableListOf()
    private var set: BarDataSet? = null
```

**API call**

```
    private val apiCall: Job
    get() =
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {

            for (i in 0 until pickedCurrs.size) {
                myPickedCurrencies += "${pickedCurrs[i]}, "
            }

            mViewModel.fetchData(
                myBaseCurrency,
                myPickedCurrencies,
                fromDate,
                toDate
            )

            mViewModel.myApiData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { status ->
                when (status) {
                    is MyWrapper.Success -> {
                        status.data?.timeSeriesRates?.entries?.forEachIndexed { index, entry ->
                            myChartData.add(
                                BarEntry(
                                    index.toFloat(),
                                    entry.value.values.map { it.toFloat() }.toFloatArray()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        makeChart(
                            myChartData,
                            formatDate(status.data?.timeSeriesRates?.keys!!.toList()),
                            mSelectedCurrencies
                        )
                    }
                    is MyWrapper.Error -> {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: ERROR")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

**makeChart**

```
      private fun prepareChart(
        entries: MutableList<BarEntry>,
        xAxisValues: ArrayList<String>,
        pickedCurrs: MutableList<String>
    ) {
        val colorsList = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val legEn = mutableListOf<LegendEntry>()

        for (i in pickedCurrs.indices) {
            val color =
                Color.argb(
                    255,
                    Random().nextInt(256),
                    Random().nextInt(256),
                    Random().nextInt(256)
                )
            if (!colorsList.contains(color)) {
                colorsList.add(color)
            }
        }
        set = BarDataSet(myEntries, "x")
        set?.colors = colorsList
        set?.highLightAlpha = 0

        val data = BarData(set)
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.data = data
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.description?.isEnabled = false
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6f)
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.barData?.setValueTextSize(12f)
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.setExtraOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 15f)
//
//        //xAxis
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.setDrawLabels(true)
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.granularity = 1f
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.textSize = 11.5f
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(myXAxisValues)
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.xAxis?.labelRotationAngle = -20f
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.axisRight?.setDrawGridLines(false)
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
//
//        //legend
        val legend = mBinding.timeSeriesChart.legend
        legend?.verticalAlignment = Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM
        legend?.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT
        legend?.orientation = Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL
        legend?.setDrawInside(false)


        for (i in pickedCurrs.indices) {
            legEn.add(
                LegendEntry(
                    pickedCurrs[i],
                    Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE,
                    15f,
                    15f,
                    null,
                    colorsList[i]
                )
            )
        }
       
        legend?.setCustom(legEn)

        set?.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                return String.format("%2.02f", value)
            }
        }
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.invalidate()
        mBinding.timeSeriesChart.refreshDrawableState()
    }
```

EDIT
stack trace

```
Process: com.example.x, PID: 15091
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
        at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:434)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LegendRenderer.renderLegend(LegendRenderer.java:377)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:281)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23889)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22756)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23892)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22756)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:5545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23892)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4944)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22756)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.drawChild(FragmentContainerView.kt:235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.dispatchDraw(FragmentContainerView.kt:225)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.drawChild(FragmentContainerView.kt:235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.dispatchDraw(FragmentContainerView.kt:225)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
```

Comment: You really need to read this before you start trying to debug anything. When your program crashes, the log tells you exactly what line of code caused the crash and why. And if you ask about crashes on this site, you will always be expected to include the stack trace in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Added stack trace.

Comment: I don't use MPAndroidChart, so I can't answer your question. Apparently there is a data inconsistency between what it expects and what you gave it. But the way you have set up your `apiCall` property is a time bomb (a bug or leak just waiting to happen). It is very unusual to launch a new coroutine every time a property is accessed. By convention, that should be a function instead of a property. Property getters generally should not have behavioral side effects.

Comment: Oh, I just realized it's a lazy coroutine, so it's not quite so bad. But I still would consider it  [astonishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). It generates a new coroutine every time it's accessed, so you can only `join()` a coroutine if you immediately use it or store it in another property. And if you join the property multiple times, you will create redundant observers.

Comment: Combining `var` with `MutableList` as you have done with `myChartData` can also be a likely source of bugs because you can modify it in two different ways and then wonder why something is not updating or why data seems inconsistent with the changes you've made. I have a feeling if you change this to a `val` or a read-only `List` type, and then fix your code to use it that way, your crash will be fixed. This seems a likely culprit judging from that stack trace.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for the tips. I'm gonna try that out now

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Call `chart.notifyDataSetChanged()` after calling `legend.setCustom(entries)`

Unfortunately I think this is a bug in MPAndroidChart. It will hit that crash if you increase the number of entries in a custom legend with notifying the chart that the dataset changed. I made a simple example that replicates this issue to test the fix.

If you run this demo problem and click the "Add Entry" button, it will crash with the same error you saw.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var entries = mutableListOf(
        BarEntry(0f, 3f),
        BarEntry(1f,2.5f),
        BarEntry(2f,4f)
    )
    private var labels = mutableListOf("Foo","Bar","Baz")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val chart = findViewById<BarChart>(R.id.chart)
        val addEntry = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_entry)

        addEntry.setOnClickListener {
            entries.add(BarEntry(entries.size.toFloat(), 3.2f))
            labels.add("Xtra")
            refreshChart(chart)
        }

        refreshChart(chart)
    }


    private fun refreshChart(chart: BarChart) {
        val colors = entries.map {
            Color.argb(
                255,
                Random.nextInt(256),
                Random.nextInt(256),
                Random.nextInt(256)
            )
        }
        val ds = BarDataSet(entries, "x")
        ds.colors = colors
        chart.data = BarData(ds)

        val legend = chart.legend
        legend.setDrawInside(false)
        val legendEntries = labels.zip(colors).map {lab_col ->
            LegendEntry(lab_col.first, Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE, 15f, 15f, null, lab_col.second)
        }

        legend.setCustom(legendEntries)
        chart.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The reason is that the array of calculated legend text widths in the Legend object ([`calculatedLabelSizes`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/0550d3f7907c635744c08ad8ff9c45e1b6281cc7/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LegendRenderer.java#L381)) isn't automatically updated to the new increased number of entries before the legend is rendered, leading to an IndexOutOfBoundsException in the LegendRenderer. The fix is to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the chart to force it to re-measure the legend and resize that internal array to match the number of legend entries before it is rendered, like this

```kotlin
legend.setCustom(legendEntries)

// This forces the legend to resize its size array to match the size
// of the newly set legendEntries array
chart.notifyDataSetChanged()

chart.invalidate()
```

Doing this, the demo works fine and new legend entries can be added without an issue.

[image: working demo]

**Note**

Your `if (!colorsList.contains(color)) {` clause also has the potential to cause your app to crash. If your random color generator ever hits a duplicate, the `colorsList` length will be too short. This is pretty unlikely, but not impossible.